# dompdf laravel if 1 div page break 2nd starts from new page how to prevent?

Tags: html, css, laravel, dompdf

So, if my left div will exceed page

[image]
like that, next div start just after it

[image]

if div 1 (red) is less than 100% height everything is fine... but if height is more and div exceed 1 page next div starts from next page

any idea how to fix it?

my css code:
red:

```
{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    padding:0.5cm;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

orange:

```
{
    padding:0.5cm;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: set page-break-before: always;

Comment: where ? to red? orange? both? wrapper?

Comment: I have spent few days for same issue, and it seems there is no solution because of dompdf rendering - it renders one way, and if during rendering of first div page breaks it continue to render on new page :( To sad, this issue is since 2016 year and still no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for a solution, you can use display:table-cell for your divs and for the wrapper div display:table !!